# Twig: type of dynamic property

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Currently, in my index page, I show the value of object properties from dynamic object and dynamic properties.

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
        {% for property in properties %}
            <td>{{ attribute(object, property) }}</td>
        {% endfor %}                  
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here both the objects and properties are dynamic. And I output the value of the property as `attribute(object, property)`. But there are **some properties** with **boolean type**. Currently those boolean properties gives output as `0` or `1`. I need to output `no` or `yes` instead of `0` or `1`. How can I do that?

One option could be to find out the type of the property. But I don't know how I can get the type of the property from dynamic object and properties.

**Edit:** most answers are considering that all the properties are boolean type. But some of them are boolean and some of them are not boolean.

Comment: i think, define an array with index 0,1 and set values as per ur need, like $t = array(0=>"No" , 1=>"Yes" ), and use $t[properties],

Comment: could you please add an example for `objects`?

Answer (score 3):

If your attribute function only returns 0,1 You can try **[ternary](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)** operator too:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
        {% for property in properties %}
            <td>{{ attribute(object, property) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
        {% endfor %}                  
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**: You can try **[in](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator)**

```
{% set boolArray = [1, 0] %}

{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
        {% for property in properties %}
            <td>
                {% if attribute(object, property) in boolArray %}
                    {{ attribute(object, property) ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                {% else %}
                    {{ attribute(object, property)}}
                {% endif%}
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As I said in the question, some of the fields are boolean not all of them

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Check my edit answer may help any thing

Answer (score 2):

### Using **same as**

You may want to consider implementing a Twig conditional statement (which can be inserting into a Twig macro) using the **[same as](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html)** Twig feature as so:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
        {% for property in properties %}
            {% if attribute(object, property) is same as(true) %}
                <td>yes</td>
            {% elseif attribute(object, property) is same as(false) %}
                <td>no</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{ attribute(object, property) }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}                  
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

---

As stated in the **[same as](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html)** documentation:

> **same as** checks if a variable is the same as another variable. This is the equivalent to === in PHP

Comment: unfortunately this always gives either true or false

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the Translation component for this kind of work, as example:

```
        <td>{{ ('label-' ~ attribute(object, property))|trans }}</td>
```

and use a translation files as example:

<kbd>Resources/translations/messages.en.yml</kbd>

```
label-1: yes
label-true: yes
label-0: no
label-false: no
```

Hope this help

Comment: but not all of my properties are boolean. and your answer consider all properties are boolean

Comment: hi @asdfkjasdfjk can you make an example? I think you can translate it however, don't you?

Comment: well, I have a list of more than 50 properties. And the output of `attribute(object, property)` is not always same. For example, if the output is the description of a user then how can I translate this?

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk you can remove the prefix and then consider to translate only the interested keys: the missing translation will be printed as origin. If you consider this approach, use a different translation catalog. Let me know  if you need more help